# Sort on Custom field in views

Tags: entities, views

I am using views 3 in D7 and have added custom field of percentage on students result listing. I want to sort on the percentage field, how can I add sort on custom field?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Your custom field is added after the query is performed by views, and a the sort is done as part of the query, therefore your sort doesn't know about your custom field.

I'd probably try to store the percentage in a field on the content type and then you'll be able to sort using the normal views sort handlers.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with using [views php](http://drupal.org/project/views_php), they have a sorting option on there.

Comment: Views php is probably the worst module on http://drupal.org